# Maximum number of docs for Solr with Cassandra

Tags: solr, cassandra

I currently have a Cassandra database with around 50,000 rows and  ~5 columns. However, when I check my numDocs/maxDocs on Core Admin using the Solr Admin UI, it only finds 10K numDocs & maxDocs. Is there a maximum that Solr is able to index? If so, where can I edit that number if possible? If not, am I doing something wrong when setting up Solr? I have every column indexed in my schema set-up.

Comment: how many Solr nodes do you have?

Comment: is this using dse or some other solr to cassandra integration?

Comment: I should only have one Solr node. I followed this tutorial to set it up WITHOUT using DSE/Datastax: https://snapdev.net/2017/08/03/install-solr-on-ubuntu-14-04-or-16-06-without-datastax-dse/

Comment: Any idea as to why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1):

The max amount of docs Solr can index is way, way larger.

You most probably have 5 solr nodes and each one is holding 10k **different** docs. Just run some query, sort by something and verify it.

DSE does not use SolrCloud, they do their own clustering stuff, so the info you see in Solr dashboard is not totally equivalent to what you see in vanilla solr.

Comment: Is there any way I can check how many solr nodes I have set up? I'm pretty sure I only set up one.

Comment: What do you mean by "just run some query, sort by something and verify it"? I'm not using DSE/Datastax btw.